# exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException",…

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am a newbie to jquery and ajax and I am using laravel in my backend,"I must say the codes below works perfectly fine for just one of my pages but other pages I get the error above".
I tried to load my jquery datatables data via ajax so I performed a jquery ajax call to my route as below:

```
ajax:
    
        {
            type    : "get",
            url     : "{{URL::asset('AgencyExpenses')}}",
            dataType: "json",
        },
        columns: 
        [
            {"data":"id"},
            {"data":"agency_id"},
            {"data":"amount"},
            {"data":"date"},
            {"data":"description"},
            {"data":"address"},
            {
                "data": null,
                render: function(data,row,type){
                    return '<button class="btn btn-trans btn-sm btn-primary fa fa-pencil text-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable" ></button>'
                }
                
            },
            {
                "data": null,
                render: function(data,row,type){
                    return '<button class="btn btn-trans btn-sm btn-danger fa fa-trash text-danger"></button>'
                }
                
            },
        ],
        autofill: true,
        select: true,
        responsive: true,
        buttons: true,
        length: 10,
    }
```

my "web.php" route is:

```
Route::get('AgencyExpenses',[AgencyExpController::class, 'expense']);
```

and my controller returns this function:

```
public function expense()
{
    $expense = AgencyExp::all();
    return response()->json([
        'data' => $expense,
    ]);
}
```

but every time the page loads this message displays:
[jquery datatable error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWS4h.png)

in network the fetch/xhr returns 404 status code with the following exceptions:

> "", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException",…}

Comment: I think the url is not valid. You can check if the route exists in the output generated by `php artisan route:list`.

Comment: What URL does `URL::asset('AgencyExpenses')` print?

Comment: @ porloscerros Ψ sorry for that, it was misspelled when pasting here, the function is "all()".

Comment: @ Adrian Zavis  this is what is printed: http://127.0.0.1:8001/AgencyExpenses?_=1636119800418

Comment: @ Sachin Bahukhandi the command "php artisan route:list" didn't display my route so I made a quick search and executed these two commands 'php artisan optimize' and 'php artisan route:clear' and the issue was solved. I really appreciate your help, thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I had to clear the routes cache by executing two command listed below:

```
php artisan optimize
```

and

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Named routes allow the convenient generation of URLs or redirects for specific routes. You may specify a `name` for a route by chaining the name method onto the route definition:

```
Route::get('AgencyExpenses',[AgencyExpController::class, 'expense'])
    ->name('agency.expense');
```

Try to change your AJAX URL :

```
{
    type    : "get",
    url     : "{{ route('agency.expense') }}",
    dataType: "json",
},
```

PS : Don't forget to clear route :

```
php artisan route:clear
```